# Get number of fragments in each primitive

Tags: opengl

Is there any way to get the count of fragments (pixels) before the depth test for each primitive (triangle)? I tried using opengl queries, but they seem to be very slow.

If there is no builtin mechanism I was considering using some image store or atomics mechanism, but I have no experience with these features. If that helps - I am able to get primitive id into the fragment shader easly, since none of my primitives share vertices.

Comment: What would be the point of such a metirc which simply does not reflect what is going on (or which would change what is going on by measuring it)? Note that the depth test is not only early, but usually also hierachical - the rasterizer will not produce fragments in some 2D tile in advance simply because it know that none of these would pass the depth test - it does not even know how many fragments it would have produced otherwise because _not having to calulate that_ whas the whole point of the optimisation in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You want a fragment count *before* the depth test? There is no way to do that at all. Not in a guaranteed way.

See, while the specification states that depth tests happen after the fragment shader, it can be costly to run a complex FS whose results get discarded due to a simple test. So the "as if" rule allows implementations to attempt to [perform fragment tests before the FS](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test), if there would be no behavioral difference between them.

However, while there is an explicit mechanism to turn force early fragment tests, there is no reverse mechanism to *preventing* early tests. And without that, what you want is impossible.

Now, because early tests are an "as if" optimization, if your FS does something which *requires* executing the fragment shader before the depth test, then you would force the implementation to not optimize your FS execution. The problem is that the only act which would *guarantee* such a thing would be changing the value of `gl_FragDepth`. The depth test is required to respect the fragment shader's `gl_FragDepth` value, so the depth test must come after the FS's execution.

The problem is that modifying `gl_FragDepth` means changing the depth of the fragment you generate, which probably isn't what you want. Oh sure, it's possible that simply having `gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;` at the top of your FS's `main` function is sufficient for an implementation to turn off early tests. But a particularly smart compiler might notice that this FS actually leaves the value of `gl_FragDepth` unchanged, since its default value really is `gl_FragCoord.z`. And therefore, it may still get early tests.

Even something like `gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z + 0;` could be optimized out; the compiler can see that you're adding nothing, after all.

If you're willing to assume that the compiler isn't smart enough to optimize `gl_FragDepth = gl_FragCoord.z` or some similar construction, then you can fabricate what you want using existing shader functionality. You can use atomic image load/store or SSBO functionality to increment the fragment counter. Helper invocations don't execute these operations, so you need not worry about that.

And if you *really* want a per-triangle/line/point fragment count, you can use `gl_PrimitiveID` to figure out which primitive you're on. This value will be increasing, starting at 0, unless a prior vertex processing stage did something to mess with it. If a geometry shader exists, then the value of `gl_PrimitiveID` is undefined unless the GS writes a value to it for that primitive. Tessellation shaders can even discard primitives, which can impact the implicit `gl_PrimitiveID`'s value in the fragment shader.

But if you're not playing around with those stages, then `gl_PrimitiveID` will be a reasonable value.